# Is there any way to return a response from XMPP after sending a message?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

When I send a message to a XMPP openfire user, I need a response of the particular user's activity. Like if he/she saw the message or not, typing a message for me or not etc. I am using Monitoring Service plugin of openfire, so I can get all chat history from there, i need to know about receiver activity about that particular message or conversation.

Now I am using strophe.js to handle all my requests and responses in my web page.

Is there any way with their plugins(like strophe) to make this..?

Can any one help me to solve this problem, i am new to XMPP openfire server.

thanks,
biswajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XEP-0184: Message Delivery Receipts - http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html

XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications - http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html

Comment: Thanks mikek !
I am trying with these links. I think it will helps me.
Thanks once again..

Comment: Hi mikek!
Problem is I have a web application that uses XMPP openfire server to communicate some chat or messages. I saw  in my console that "http://hostname/xmpp-httpbind" is call each time for presence. I have authenticate it using my web app's user credential.

But when I refresh the page I see that the connection is got a problem and also got disconnected from XMPP server. So I need to reconnect it on the page load, I already did it but some time the Authentication take long time before connect.

Do you have some solution for my problem? I need authentication fast.

Thanks ,
biswajit

Comment: Try Strophe's attach(). This should get you started: http://metajack.im/2008/10/03/getting-attached-to-strophe/